# Dart Polymer Conditional Template Creation Complete?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I’ll do some work after a conditional template is instantiated.

Like this:

```dart
<polymer-element name="xyz-test">
  <template>
    <template if="{{xyz}}">
          <div class="main">
             <div class="sub1"> </div>
             <div class="sub2"> </div>
          </div>
    </template>
  </template>
  <script type="application/dart" src="my_test.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

.

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';

@CustomTag('xyz-test"')
class XyzText extends PolymerElement {

  // After the Conditional Templates are created, 
  // I wish to work with the Elements in them.

  DocumentFragment instanceTemplate(Element template) {
    // Is not working for Conditional Templates
  }


  @override
   Node shadowFromTemplate(Element template) {
    // Is not working for Conditional Templates
   }
}
```

Perhaps somebody can give me any Idea.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to call a method (or getter) on your XyzTest class.

```dart
class="{{getClass()}}"
```

Comment: Yes I know. But I want to do more complicated things after the whole Conditional Template is instantiated.

Comment: Maybe MutationObserver may help in your case. Search for it here on SO or dart-polymer-dart-examples.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer but it doesn't work under all circumstances.